# I have used ChannelDescriptor to get channel and then call getUnconsumedMessagesCount but still get 0 count for android sdk in twilio chat

Tags: android, twilio

i am using twilio android sdk for chat. instant chat is working fine, but getUnconsumedMessagesCount() method always returning zero.

i have set allmessagesconsumed for a member of the channel in the channel(every time after sending message). but i cant get unread message count.

Comment: Please post your code here in the question instead of trying to describe it.

Comment: If you've set all messages consumed, then the unconsumed count will be 0. Perhaps you can share your code and a bit more detail about what you are expecting.